# How to render Path geometry without Window Handle using Windows Store C++

Tags: c#, c++, xaml, windows-store-apps, direct2d

In my Windows Store application, I have to draw the Path geometry using Direct2D in C++. In my  scenario instead of using basic `Polyline` object, i go for Direct2D for better performance in my application. So my C# application will communicate with the C++ component for the Direct2D drawing.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee264309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) link helped to get more information about Direct2D drawing for `PathGeometry`. But it draws the geometry in the Window Handle but rather than using Window handle i need the drawing to be done as like the ordinary `UIElement` rendering. Is there any sample available over the net to resolve my problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to use the factory that created the SurfaceImageSource; We should not create a new factory.  So our will have code like this:

```
 ID2D1Factory *pFactory=nullptr;
 d2dDevice->GetFactory(&pFactory);
 ID2D1GeometrySink *pSink = NULL;
 ID2D1PathGeometry *pPathGeometry=NULL;
 // Create a path geometry.
 HRESULT hr = pFactory->CreatePathGeometry(&pPathGeometry);
```

Finally it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are samples for DirectX/XAML integration and I think there might even be a VS project template for integrating these that includes Direct2D code, though possibly in a single project natice C++ app, whereas you would need to create a native WinRT component that exposes a C++/CX API to your application to put in either a `SwapChainPanel` (best option, but requires Windows 8.1), `SwapChainBackgroundPanel` (good option, but full-screen only) or a `SurfaceImageSource`.

Comment: May i get any available samples to draw the PathGeometry using SurfaceImageSource ?